# Trying to sync zip file using git LFS, says I'm out of space

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I have a zip file that's about 600MB. I have the file setup to track using LFS. The zip changes frequently so I need to update it in the remote repo often.

I have no problem pushing the file to LFS if my LFS storage is empty. However, when I try to push it if the file already exists in LFS, I get an error: "Your LFS push failed because you're out of file storage". The updated file is still not more than 600MB. I have a 1 GB limit with Bitbucket.

My assumption was that the file would just be updated on remote with each push if it has changed. However, that apparently is not true. In order to get the file pushed to remote, I have to manually login to Bitbucket and delete the file from LFS so I can push the updated version.

I'm assuming I am not doing something correctly and shouldn't need to manually delete my LFS to push changes to remote. I apparently am gravely misunderstanding how to use git LFS.

My apologies if this topic already exists. I swear I tried looking for it.

Comment: LFS has no way of knowing who's cloned your repo. All repositories are peers, `cp -a` clones in many sense more faithfully than git's selective-repack-and-cleanup clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that LFS tries to upload the new version of large file before deleting the previous one? If this is the case you need at least 1.2GB in order to update a 600MB file.

To test it, you could try with a smaller test version of the zip file (about 300MB). If you are able to update it and logging in Bitbucket you find previous version is no longer there, you know the problem is your 1GB limit.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's it, it's a possibility. It's a good idea to test the smaller files. I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: I tested your theory with a smaller zip file. You're partly correct.

Comment: Apparently LFS does not update the same file if it has changed, but it stores it as a completely different file. So it's not necessarily working like normal git where it tracks changes, but instead acts more like a snapshot or backup. However, using LFS makes no sense if the zip file also has to be tracked in regular git tracking. So using LFS to get around storage limits for large files is pointless. Since your help led me to an answer, I'll award the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: LFS is not really for getting around any limits, it's for managing large files differently. With normal Git, any checkout will necessarily give you every file. With LFS, it may wait to give you the large files until you actually need them, for example, so you don't use bandwidth and wait for everything to load if you only need to use other files.

Answer (score 0):

For any object storage(zip file, blob etc), the whole file is uploaded and a pointer is created to keep track of latest version. If blob size is more than your allocated quota, you will face space issue as 2 different versions of same blob(of almost same size) will actually double the space usage.